# Hook into existing tinyMCE button

Tags: plugins, hooks, tinymce, plugin-tinymce

Is there a way to hook into an existing tinyMCE editor button?

I have a plugin that currently has a button on the editor and it shows a popup-box when clicked. This box has tabs inside.

I would like to be able to create another plugin but check if the button already exists, if it exists then I would like this second plugin to add another tab inside this popup-box.

Is there a hook in wordpress or tinyMCE that would allow me to hook into this button?

Thanks